# Programming projectile gravity around stationary bodies

Tags: physics, game-physics, gravity

I want to imitate the gravity in this video:

[Bombardier Gravity Gameplay Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51xSdjE_s-M)

The bodies are stationary and don't affect each other. Projectiles are fired with a set velocity & angle. They approach a planet, slow down, then make tight twists and speed up.

When I've implemented gravity using Newton's equation objects have always moved wonkier -- speeding up and shooting off ridiculously fast. Maybe it's a matter of tweaking the mass.

Just curious what techniques people use, if vanilla Newton's is good, advice on mass ratios, anything else you think is important for programming this kind of motion.

Comment: A good thing to do when working with radial gravity is to make sure that you either have good collision detection or a max(); on the force generated by gravity to make sure that 2 objects don't pass directly through each other and recieve massive boosts in velocity for it. Also,  the smaller your physics step is the better.

Comment: "the smaller your physics step is the better" - Not true. Decreasing the time step increases the amount of time the integration requires and no one wants their simulations to crawl. Also, there are regions of the motion where the motion is slow, in which case a larger time step is fine. Moreover, decreasing the time step too much can get you close to the floating point precision of your hardware in which case your answers suffer badly from roundoff errors and become totally bogus. The best approach is to automatically select a time step based on the current speed.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your implementation has the projectiles sometimes speeding up and shooting off ridiculously fast is that there are several time scales and length scales involved in this problem but your integration step is oblivious to them. Rather than tweak the masses, it's best to tweak your integration step to respond to those various time and length scales, which will then keep your numbers from getting too large.

Say you have a single projectile of mass *m* and a number of planets of masses *Mk*, located at fixed position vectors **R***k*. If the projectile's position vector is **r**, then *Newton's equations* give you

[image]

for the projectile's acceleration *d^2***r***/dt^2* and

[image]

for the projectile's velocity *d***r***/dt*, where *E* is the total energy (which is a constant of the motion).

Now imagine, for a moment, that you had only one planet of mass *M* and that you had the projectile orbiting it in an elliptical orbit of semi-major axis *a* and period *T*. Then *Kepler's third law* tells you that

[image]

Of course, you don't have a single planet and the projectile is not orbiting those planets in a single elliptical orbit. In fact, its orbit may not even be closed. Still, rather than tweak the planets' masses, think of tweaking the time-scales and length-scales that they're responsible for in the projectile's motion. Those time and length scales are approximately given by the expression above, at least in those cases where the orbits are nearly elliptical. So, instead of using *Mk*, use

[image]

as a proxy for the planet masses. The equations you want to integrate then become

[image]

for the projectile's acceleration *d^2***r***/dt^2* and

[image]

for the projectile's velocity *d***r***/dt*.

Now, why are these better than the original equations? Because you can select, ahead of time, the various periods and semi-major axes, which then define the various time and length scales of the projectile's orbit. Those, in turn, help you decide what integration steps to use at various points during the orbit and that helps to give you both a more accurate orbit as well as a better-behaved numerical problem to solve.

For example, say you have 3 planets. Rather than arbitrarily set their masses and hope for the best, say you choose *a1 = 100 pixels*, *T1 = 5 seconds*, *a2 = 200 pixels*, *T2 = 10 seconds*, *a3 = 150 pixels* and *T3 = 30 seconds*. These numbers tell you that, roughly, the first projectile will move *2pi x 100 pixels* in *5 seconds*, that is, its speed is roughly *120 pixels per second*. The others move at roughly *120 pixels/sec* and *30 pixels/sec*. At *120 pixels/sec*, if you want to integrate one pixel per time step, you'll need roughly *100 time steps per second*, so your time step should never be much larger than *0.01 second*.

Again, these are not exact considerations because the orbit is not necessarily closed and Kepler's 3rd law as stated above is only valid for a 2-body problem with a closed orbit. Still, framing the equations in the form above and carefully choosing and monitoring your integration step to agree with the time scales inherent to the problem will make your simulation much more stable and accurate.

For actual help with implementing adaptive integration methods for systems of ordinary differential equations (an example of which is this problem), have a look at [adaptive Runge-Kutta methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Adaptive_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_methods).

Comment: It's going to take me a bit to read through and comprehend this. Thank you for posting!

Comment: You're most welcome. I've edited my answer to add better renderings of the equations so they're easier to read and also clarified the text a little in a few places. I hope this is useful to you (and others).

Answer (score 2):

A very simple, physically incorrect, but effective approach (used even in many-body simulations on GPU's) is to "cut out the singularities" by ensuring that the denominator in your -GmM/r^2 never becomes zero. This can be done by simply adding a positive constant to the denominator:

```
 |F| = G*m*M/(r^2 + c)
```

This lets the "planets" appear not like infinitely dense points of mass, but instead as blurry clouds of matter. This eliminates the problem with projectiles that abruptly accelerate to extreme velocities. Human players will never notice any difference anyway.

Comment: I have used this method with some success with c as small as 10^-10 is good.

Comment: One more alternative is realizing that the inverse square f=k/r^2 changes to Hook's law f=kr at very small distances due to electrical forces. This law then works as a spring force that doesn't have a singularity at r=0.